# To ignore special characters and html code of a string and store the words in to one column of a table

Tags: java, string, stringtokenizer

I have a Code,

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
class CountWords{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String st=input.nextLine();
        int count=0;
        StringTokenizer stk=new StringTokenizer(st," ");
        while(stk.hasMoreTokens()){
            String token=stk.nextToken();
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of words are: "+count);
    }
}
```

I hava a requirement that given a input as string like 
    **"This Is the!@* text to did() madam#$  split  in *to* words."**

### o/p:-

```
Number of words are: 10
```

and

I have to count the no. of words of the string by neglecting the special characters of the string and store into a table column and also store the reverse of the word in another table column like(ignoring special characters in the string)

```
sno    words     reverse
----   ------   --------
1       This      sihT
2       Is         sI
3       the       eht  
4       text      text
```

so.... on
and if there are palindromes in the string,then kept that words in separate table like

```
word   palindrome
----   ---------
did     did
madam   madam
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: CharUtils from apache commons might fulfill the requirement

Comment: Define "special characters", please

Comment: Provide some examples of what you want. For instance what should the count be in the sentence you mention?

Comment: What is the expected string after ignoring special characters?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with messy HTML is messy.  Use an HTML cleaner utility, such as [HtmlCleaner](http://htmlcleaner.sourceforge.net/) to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "This is the!@* text to be in words.";
    str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]+", "");
    System.out.println(str);
    int len = str.split("\\s+").length;
    System.out.println(len);
}
```

I assume special character is other than alphabet and digits.

Output:

```
This is the text to be in words
8
```